# wp_set_auth_cookie() doesn't work in Ajax call

Tags: ajax, login, cookies

I am trying to create a Facebook JS-SDK based auto login feature. When user is "Connected" passing FbID and aother user data to an ajax function which creates the session cookie. Cookie is created (I can see `"wordpress_logged_in_.... cookie"` in the browser inspector) but when I reload the page the user is still logged out.

Do you have idea why?

**JavaScript**

```
function ajaxloginFB(uid,email,first_name,last_name) {
    data =  "uid=" + uid + "&" + "name=" + last_name + " " + first_name + "&" + "email=" + email + "&" + $.param({ action: 'facebook_login', nonce: ajax_object.ajaxnonce });
    $.ajax({
        url : ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        type: "post",
        data : data,
        success:function(response){
            var response = $.parseJSON(response);
            if (response.success == true){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_facebook_login', 'facebook_ajax_login_or_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_facebook_login', 'facebook_ajax_login_or_register' );

function facebook_ajax_login_or_register(){
  $uid = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['uid'] );
  $args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'fbuid',
    'meta_value'   => $uid,
    'meta_compare' => '=',
  );
  $fb_user = get_users($args);
  $current_user_id = $fb_user[0];
  wp_set_auth_cookie( $current_user_id, true );
  $response[success] = true;
  echo json_encode($response);
  die();
}
```

Comment: For one you need to use `wp_signon()` before setting the auth cookie. Second, it may not work in ajax because cookies are set by sending headers.

Answer (score 2):

I add one function [wp_set_current_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_current_user) for setting up current user.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_facebook_login', 'facebook_ajax_login_or_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_facebook_login', 'facebook_ajax_login_or_register' );

function facebook_ajax_login_or_register(){
  $uid = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['uid'] );
  $args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'fbuid',
    'meta_value'   => $uid,
    'meta_compare' => '=',
  );
  $fb_user = get_users($args);
  $current_user_id = $fb_user[0];
  wp_set_current_user($current_user_id);//Set current user
  wp_set_auth_cookie( $current_user_id, true );
  $response[success] = true;
  echo json_encode($response);
  die();
}
```

I'm not tested this so let me know if still you facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use ajax with xhr authentication header for my custom wp login

```
$.ajax({
     url : ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
});
```